# ASP.Net Worker Process Freezes when Debugger is Attached

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I see a lot of questions for Visual Studio hanging when attacking the debugger.  Mine is the opposite (maybe).  When I attach Visual Studio 2010 to a remote w3wp process, the w3wp process hangs.  Requests just sit and won't process until I stop detach.  The application doesn't recycle.  Unfortunately there's so many prominent hanging when attaching the debugger question its hard to find a solution for the reverse.  Hoping someone here has an idea.

Its a brand new Windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2010 attaching to Windows 2008 server.

I've tried running as administrator.  It didn't help.

I've tried attaching to a local process (that works).

I've tried attaching to a different managed 4.0 w3wp process on the same remote server.  I can successfully debug those without freezing.  Being attached to that process, as expected, does not freeze the website I'm having trouble with.

I was successfully debugging on the process in question on the Windows XP machine I just replaced.

I've reset IIS.  I've restarted the remote debugger service on the remote server.

Only seems to freeze up when I select 'Managed 4.0' for the debugging options (of course thats what I need to debug).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Downloading SP1 for VS2010 now, not sure if it came through windows update or not.

Comment: What do you mean by remote debugging? Are you debugging on a box other than your box? Even though possible, that has been problematic since before .NET.

Comment: @Gregory, yes the visual studio remote debugger service has to be installed on the machine you're debugging on and then you use attach to process and specify the machine to debug on.  Its been very useful, just having issues in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I didn't have a whole bunch, but I deleted all my breakpoints (Debug - Delete all breakpoints) and all of a sudden the page loaded.  I did this while attached.  So something was a bit fluky there.  Hope this saves someone else some day ;)

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: It's crazy that this is still an issue 6 years later. Even though there have been multiple versions of VS released since then, they still have not fixed this issue!